# Canvas convert to JPG with white background

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am facing similar problem [Canvas convert to JPG with white background](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/2551) and my issue is [this](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/2551#issuecomment-383898172).

Advice/suggestion is welcomed.

Thanks

Edit : 
I have a canvas where I am creating some shapes, now I need to show preview of a canvas and also to send canvas data to server (all conversions is in 'jpg'), what actually is happening the canvas area comes out black and I need that in white color. I have tried `canvas.setBackgroundColor('rgba(255, 255, 255,1)', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));` Or `canvas.background = 'white';canvas.renderAll()`  but no luck, it is still coming in black.

When I have checked `canvas.toJSON()`, it shows `rgba(255, 255, 255,1)`.

PS : my fabric version is `1.6.2`

Here is the output [black background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Miu.png)

Comment: Please explain your whole question and include what you have tried so far.

Comment: Add a white rectangle the size of the canvas as a quick easy fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed now.

It was happening because of the clipped region. Thanks to @AndreaBogazzi for helping out.
you can check here [When clipped canvas exported as JPG gives black background](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/4937).